# React js cannot set property of setstate in axios response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I get data from axios, I need to set the response in state value to render in html, when I print `response.results` it shows data, but if I set the `response.results` in `setState()` and print the `setState()` it shows empty value.

My code is:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    var headers = {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "AccessToken":localStorage.AccessToken,
      }
      var apiURL = window.$_APIurl+"companies";
      axios.get(apiURL, {headers: headers})
      .then((response) => {   
        console.log(response.data.results);        
          if(response.data.results.length > 0)
            {               
            this.setState({               
                "comapanyDetails": response.data.results,
            });
            }  
      })
    console.log(this.state.comapanyDetails)
    console.log(localStorage.toggleClass);
   
    
  }
```

It shows empty array the value is not set in `setState()`.

Comment: What are the console values?
Seperate these like this
console.log('before',response.data.results);

Comment: console response.data.results.length as well

Comment: console.log(response.results) shows value, but console.log(this.state.comapanyDetails) is not showing i need it to map data and render in html

Comment: Are you facing any issue in rendering the data?If yes, update your question with your HTML code

Comment: Yes my html Code is :

Comment: {this.state.comapanyDetails.length > 0 ?   
        <tbody>           
            {this.state.comapanyDetails.map((ComapanyDetails,indx)=>
            <tr key={indx}>                 
               
                <td>{comapanyDetails.name}</td>
                <td><Link to={{ pathname: '/'}}
                 style={{color:'#434b50'}}>{comapanyDetails.name}</Link></td>       
            </tr>
            )}
        </tbody> :
        <tbody className="noResult">
            <tr>
           <td>No Results Found</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>   
         }

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check. Also you can edit your question to put the HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` are async operations. Hence it's not guaranteed that you will see the updated value when you console a state just after setting it.

Your Html is this:

```
{this.state.comapanyDetails.length > 0 ?
<tbody> {this.state.comapanyDetails.map((ComapanyDetails,indx)=> 
<tr key={indx}> <td>{comapanyDetails.name}</td> <td><Link to={{ pathname: 
'/'}} style={{color:'#434b50'}}>
{comapanyDetails.name}</Link></td> </tr> )} </tbody> : <body 
className="noResult"> <tr> <td>No Results Found</td> </tr> </tbody> }
```

The issue is with the name. In your map function you are using the variable `ComapanyDetails`, however inside the td stage you are using comapanyDetails. Use `ComapanyDetails` or change `ComapanyDetails` to `comapanyDetails`

Comment: Even i dont need to console it but i need to use it to map and render values in return

Answer (score 0):

Check if it will work

console.log(this.state.comapanyDetails && this.state.comapanyDetails)

if your data is array

console.log(this.state.comapanyDetails.length > 0 && this.state.comapanyDetails)

Answer (score 0):

You are logging it outside of async function (axios.get). At time you are logging it the value is empty. If you want to log it correctly put it inside `.then(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

It shows empty array because the get request is running in asynchronous way, you are reading the value of the state before it is seted.
in your render you should validate the data is already loaded before show.
Example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{

 componentDidMount() {
    var headers = {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "AccessToken":localStorage.AccessToken,
      }
      var apiURL = window.$_APIurl+"companies";
      axios.get(apiURL, {headers: headers})
      .then((response) => {   
        console.log(response.data.results);        
          if(response.data.results.length > 0)
            {               
            this.setState({               
                "comapanyDetails": response.data.results,
            });
            }  
      })
  }
  render() {
    return ({this.state.comapanyDetails.length > 0 ?
             <!-- here your code for loaded data -->:
             <h1> Loading </h1>});
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use await and async as axios calls asynchronously

```
componentDidMount() {
    var headers = {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "AccessToken":localStorage.AccessToken,
      }
      var apiURL = window.$_APIurl+"companies";
      const a = (async function(){
        await axios.get(apiURL, {headers: headers})
      .then((response) => {   
        console.log(response.data.results);        
          if(response.data.results.length > 0)
            {               
            this.setState({               
                "comapanyDetails": response.data.results,
            });
            }  
      })
      }
    console.log(this.state.comapanyDetails)
    console.log(localStorage.toggleClass);
   
    
  }
```